# Want to Save Posted Json data to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am posting JSON data through AJAX POST  as ::

```
var length = $('.organizer-media').length;
                var contents = $('.organizer-media');

                var  Title;
                type == "New" ? Title = $('#newName').val() : Title = $('#Playlist option:selected').text();

                var playlistid = $('#Playlist').val()
                type == "New" ? playlistid = 0 : playlistid = $('#Playlist').val()

                var data = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    data[i] = { ID: parseInt(contents[i].id), MetaID: parseInt(contents[i].title) }
                }
               var totaldata={ data: data, playlistid: parseInt(playlistid),Title:Title };    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.Stringify(totaldata),
                    url: '/Builder/Save',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");
                    }
                })
```

the JSON data is sent in following format::

```
{"data":[{"ID":779389,"MetaID":774367},{"ID":779390,"MetaID":774367},{"ID":779387,"MetaID":774366},{"ID":779388,"MetaID":774366},{"ID":779386,"MetaID":774365},{"ID":779385,"MetaID":774364},{"ID":779384,"MetaID":774363},{"ID":779383,"MetaID":774362},{"ID":779382,"MetaID":774361},{"ID":779381,"MetaID":774360},{"ID":779378,"MetaID":774359},{"ID":779379,"MetaID":774359},{"ID":779377,"MetaID":774358},{"ID":779376,"MetaID":774357},{"ID":779375,"MetaID":774356},{"ID":779372,"MetaID":774355},{"ID":779373,"MetaID":774355},{"ID":779374,"MetaID":774354},{"ID":779370,"MetaID":774353},{"ID":779394,"MetaID":774370}],"playlistid":1461,"Title":"MX OPEN TALENT MARIA"}:
```

and as I made an ItemViewModel as ::

```
public class ItemEditViewModel
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long MetaID { get; set; }
    }
```

and My controller code is as::

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ItemEditViewModel[] data,long playlistid=0, string Title="")
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                var pc = db.PlaylistContents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PlaylistContentId == data[i].ID);
                if (pc == null)
                {
                    pc = new PlaylistContent();
                    db.PlaylistContents.Add(pc);
                }
                pc.ContentMetaDataId = data[i].MetaID;
                pc.PlaylistContentSequenceId = i + 1;
            }
db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }
```

while Execution of data in controller it doesn't accept the POSTED data as its ViewModel values.

Comment: Might want to give Glimpse a try: http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: How is the JSON parsed?

Comment: what is this glimpse?  @Tieson T

Comment: I just have to save JSON data passed into the ViewModel

Comment: @RahulRJ Basically Firebug for the server side of things. It lets you see how the routing and binding mechanisms in your ASP.NET app actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved.
As I have Posted array in combination with two other variables, I just need to stringify array & not the whole ajax data which is to be posted.
as you can see in my code below::

```
 var totaldata =  { data: data, playlistid: parseInt(playlistid), Title: Title };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { data: JSON.stringify(data), playlistid: parseInt(playlistid), Title: Title, deleted: JSON.stringify(deleted) },
                    traditional:true,
                    url: 'Save',
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");

                    }
                })
```

In above code I have just done stringify on array & not on other data.

Thanks for some Co-operations of yours.